# What is a 'product' in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

In plain English, what is a 'product' in Google Analytics?

I ask because I'm trying to work out which Custom Metrics to set to Scope:Hit and which to set to Scope:Product. I assume a "hit" is just like the website hits we used to talk about in the 90s. But Google's explanation only makes sense if you also know what they mean by "product".

> When a custom dimension has product-level scope, the value is only
>   applied to the product with which the value is set. Because multiple
>   products can be sent in a single hit, multiple product-level scoped
>   custom dimensions can be sent in a single hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know product data only exists with the new enhanced e-commerce-features** and is identified by one of the (unique) fields "id" or "name". There a several optional fields to add product details ([see documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#product-impression)).

The difference between "normal" and enhaced e-commerce tracking is that previously product data was recorded only on the confirmation pages, now you can do stuff like tracking a shopping basket or product lists (plus you need a different tracking library and a different syntax).

** At least all examples I found refered to enhanced ecommerce tracking and the classic e-commerce tracking does not have an "id" field. However the documentation does not explicitly say that product scope does not work with classic ecommerce, that's just an educated guess if mine.